# Syntax to allow admin to see all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display the page if the page is public. If the user of the page is trying to view the page if it's private and if it's the admin trying to view the page.

I have written

```
 <% if @user.is_public == true || session[:user_id] ==  @user.id %>
 <%= render "public_page" %>
 <% else %>
 Private Page
 <%end%>
```

I don't know how to add something like below to the mix. Any ideas?

```
<% unless session[:site_admin] %>
```

The purpose is to allow the site admin to view all private pages.

Comment: Is the 'public_page' partial the page in question and *Private Page* is a text shown to users who have no permission to access it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the check to the if:

```
<% if @user.is_public == true || session[:user_id] ==  @user.id || session[:site_admin] %>
  <%= render "public_page" %>
<% else %>
  Private Page
<%end%>
```

Btw, the more *ruby* way of naming `is_public` method would be `public?`

Btw btw, if your project is big and you want solid permission management it's a good practice to use Devise gem combined with CanCanCan. You then define all permissions in a single place, `models/ability.rb` and check permissions with `can? :read, @post`.